# Timeouts with long running ASP.NET MVC Core Controller HTTPPost Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, timeout

I make use of  ajax call in my `ASP.NET Core MVC` view pages

MyView.cshtml

```
          $.ajax({
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: new FormData(this),
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                        $('#mydiv).html(data);
                        $('#bootstrapModal).modal('show');
```

Controller Post method"

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyLongRunningMethod(MyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        await MyProcess.Longprocess1();
        await MyProcess.Longprocess2();
        await MyProcess.Longprocess3();
        await MyProcess.Longprocess4();
        return PartialView("_MyPartialPage");
    }
```

This works but only has an issue for a long running process. I get the following error during debug mode when the process takes longer than around 2 minutes

[image]

I understand this is to do with expiration timeout

in previous versions of ASP.NET MVC you can apparently increase the timeout in your asp.net controller action.

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 90000;
```

However this doesn't exist in `ASP.NET Core`

I want to increase the timeout for debugging and deployment for a particular asp.net controller.

For production I can set it globally in the `web.config` by adding requestTimeout to the existing httpPlatform tag.
e.g. for 10 minutes

```
<httpPlatform requestTimeout="00:10:00" ....
```

A similar question was asked but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637488/how-do-i-set-the-request-timeout-for-one-controller-action-in-an-asp-net-5-mvc-6) giving using an `CancellationToken` but reading it, it doesn't seem it can help me with the timeouts.

1. How do I set the timeouts in Visual Studio 2015 debug mode like I can do when I deploy it?
2. IS there a per controller timeout setting like there was in `ASP.NET 4`?

Comment: Changes in VS debug mode described below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172284/502-error-upload-csv-file-to-web-api?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 60, accepted):

But in .Net Core 2.0 there is no `web.config` file in project. It generate automatically.

I solved the problem by adding `.UseKestrel(...)` to the `BuildWebHost` function in `Program.cs` file as follows:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel(o => { o.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); })
        .Build();
}
```

**... Update for .net Core 6 ...**

in `Program.cs` file after

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

add `ConfigureKestrel` for `WebHost` like this

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(c =>
{
   c.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
});
```

Comment: This would be the best answer as by default web.config is not in the project.

Comment: This did not solve my issue, I still get 502 error, maybe because web.config is present in the project

Comment: Do you have 2.0 project?

Comment: when you publish the application with "dotnet publish" it generate the web.config so you can modify it

Comment: It works for me also. Thanks

Comment: one important thing to note here is that will only work in Out-of-process hosting model as The requestTimeout attribute doesn't apply to in-process hosting : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#in-process-hosting-model-1

Comment: How to set with just the one method, seems bad to have a high timeout for all controller methods?

Answer (score 52):

Setting the `RequestTimeout="00:20:00"` on the `aspNetCore` tag and deploying the site will cause it not to timeout.

Issue now only occurs when running from Visual Studio debug mode but not in release mode.

Take note: In ASP.NET RTM the `httpPlatform` tag has been replaced with  `aspNetCore` in the `web.config`

Example for ASP.NET Core

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00"  processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This causes a 502 bad gateway when you F5

Comment: Using .net core 1.1 now and this seems to be working!

Comment: @firste did you find any solution for debug mode??

Comment: If you are running in Visual Studio, try to run in Console Mode instead of IIS.  You should see an option that is the same name as your solution name in the dropdown that shows IIS, and this option does not seem to have the timeout limit.

Comment: Works with 2.0 too

Comment: Not to timeout ever? Even after the 20 minutes set?

Comment: Note, I don't think this works with .net core 3.1+ if you are using in-process hosting. `requestTimeout` is apparently not supported for this hosting model.

Answer (score 23):

In my case we still had the 502 timeout error at 2 minutes even after updating the `requestTimeout` parameter. It turned out that kestrel has a 2 minute keep alive timeout which needed to be overridden:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
               .UseKestrel(o =>
                    {
                        o.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                    }
                )
```

Comment: 'KestrelServerOptions' does not contain a definition for 'Limits'. This is not an ASP.NET Core 1.0 solution.

Comment: Appears to exist in 2.2

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer has changed since .Net Core 3.1. In NET Core 3.1 use the following implementation to increase KeepAliveTimeout:

Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
                });
            });
```

Web.Config (You need to add the config file to your project if it doesn't exist.)

Increase requestTimeout as required on the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:15:00"  processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thx for this - just confirming: is this an AND or an OR ie, do both or one or the other?

Comment: @toy I had to do both to get it working properly.

Comment: Web.config requestTimeout still won't do anything at all if you are hosting inprocess.

Answer (score 9):

for me this worked:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureKestrel(o => { o.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); });
```

Answer (score 4):

For .net core 6.0

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(t =>
{
   t.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio not appear file web.config in Solution Explore. I fixed adding the file in Solution and changed the property "Copy to output Directory".