# ASP.Net Core Killing execution during long running operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, timeout

I have a long-running insert query that takes multiple minutes to complete. ASP.Net Core seems to kill the execution part way though the process.

It looks like this has to do with the execution timeout for ASP.Net, however, the solutions that I could find are not applicable to ASP.Net Core.

How can I increase the execution time limit for that controller action?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474309/timeouts-with-long-running-asp-net-mvc-core-controller-httppost-method

Comment: @JohnKoerner that just causes a `502 bad gateway` error. Though it looks like it would affect the application in it's entirety anyways, I would only want to apply this to a specific controller action.

Comment: What are you using to host the site (kestrel, IIS)?

Comment: @JohnKoerner IIS Express