# Request timeout in dot net core mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-core, timeout, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm calling a controller method from my view that has some long process to do

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyControllerMethod(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    await MyFile.Longprocess);
    return PartialView("_MyPartialPage");
}
```

I get the following error during debug mode when the process takes longer than around 2 minutes

> An Error occurred: Status: error, Description: Bad Gateway

Sadly I didn't find any solution of `scriptTimeout` in `ASP .NET Core` like we have in MVC

> HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 90000;

After some RnD, I [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38507709/2660342) that Setting the `RequestTimeout="00:30:00"` on the `aspNetCore` tag will work out in release mode only and Issue still occurs when running from Visual Studio debug mode.

So is there any way to set the timeouts in Visual Studio 2017 debug mode? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which web server is used? Are you use different servers on debug and release?

Comment: IIS, no..same web servers both times

Comment: This is already answered on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474309/timeouts-with-long-running-asp-net-mvc-core-controller-httppost-method