# ASP.NET Core deployed on IIS returns 502 Error for long running requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 web application which is hosted on IIS 10 on Windows Server 2012 without any load balancing and special configurations. For some MVC actions which takes too long we get a 502 HTTP error.

[image]

After seeing this error I was shocked, because I didn't have any configuration for a proxy server, etc. And then I remembered that the ASP.NET Core runs on Kestrel. So I came to this conclusion that here IIS plays the role of the proxy server and forwards the requests to the Kestrel. So I think this is somehow related to a timeout configuration, as the other parts of the application works very well. I have searched for similar questions on SO but no luck finding a solution.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/48

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timeouts with long running ASP.NET MVC Core Controller HTTPPost Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474309/timeouts-with-long-running-asp-net-mvc-core-controller-httppost-method)

Comment: Long-running tasks should be run in the background, especially if it takes so long that the request is timing out. You can use something like Hangfire or in ASP.NET Core 2.0, you can use `IHostedService`. In either case, your action should schedule the task and then return immediately. You can then use SignalR to monitor the status and update the user when the task has completed.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thank you Chris for that point. I will check it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, ASP.NET Core request time out is 2 minutes, and you can change it via requestTimeout in setting file. See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module)

> requestTimeout     Optional timespan attribute.
>
> Specifies the duration for which the ASP.NET Core Module will wait for
>   a response from the process listening on %ASPNETCORE_PORT%.
>
> The default value is "00:02:00".
>
> The requestTimeout must be specified in whole minutes only, otherwise
>   it defaults to 2 minutes.

Comment: Any other ideas ... this doesn't fix my problem, request is clearly timing out will under the configured length of time with the same error.

Answer (score 10):

I am getting same error when data is huge and take more time to execute web page, I have changed timeout value for .netcore in web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" 
           resourceType="Unspecified"/>
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00"  processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" 
          arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
         stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

I have add `requestTimeout="00:20:00"` in my existing web.config file and it works.

for reference go to this [url](https://medium.com/aspnetcore/increase-the-timeout-of-asp-net-core-application-9a7b4f6deebf)

Comment: What about just .NET and not .NET Core? I can't seem to solve it even with increasing the `executionTimeout` nor `sessionState` to a really high number.