# Can you set request timeout in asp.net core 2.0 hosted in IIS from C# code?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a way to set `requestTimeout` from C# instead of needing to set `requestTimeout` in the `web.config`?

asp.net core 2.0 hosted in IIS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:00:04" processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Foo.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[Not like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38507709/1228889)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No, there is no way to do that** as you described. But according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) **you can just add web.config to your project** and specify this (and other) setting value:

> If a `web.config` file **isn't present** in the project, the file is created
>   with the correct processPath and arguments to configure the ASP.NET
>   Core Module and moved to published output.
>
> If a `web.config` file **is present** in the project, the file is
>   transformed with the correct processPath and arguments to configure
>   the `ASP.NET Core Modul`e and moved to published output. **The
>   transformation doesn't modify IIS configuration settings in the file**.
>
> The `web.config` file may provide additional `IIS` configuration settings
>   that control active `IIS` modules. For information on `IIS` modules that
>   are capable of processing requests with `ASP.NET Core` apps, see the `IIS`
>   modules topic.
>
> To prevent the Web SDK from transforming the web.config file, use the
>   `IsTransformWebConfigDisabled` property in the project file.

Comment: How to add Web.config if it's not present..." the file is created with the correct processPath and arguments to configure the ASP.NET Core Module " means? could please elaborate.

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar123456 when you use IIS `web.config` is generated after you publish your web project. But you can just add this file to the porject root. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configuration-of-iis-with-webconfig) to see what can be configured, what not, and how to configure the rest.

Comment: I tried...I add web.config in my .net core 2.0 project and add Request timeout of 20 min for a request in API project. but still no luck...Same error getting when the Mobile app sends huge data...for publish we use Azure server hence don't know exactly what settings Azure server have.

Comment: If you are using an InProcess hosting model, the requestTimeout attribute in the Web.Config is ignored.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1#in-process-hosting-model

Comment: so how to activate if the hostingmodel is inprocess sir?

Comment: @toha this should fo the trick `<PropertyGroup><AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel></PropertyGroup>` - see [In-process hosting with IIS and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/in-process-hosting)