# Asp.Net Core Web API returns the result while client is hanging

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple Asp.Net Core Web API with .NET 6, running on IIS 10, Windows 10. The web API calls another API and returns the results. Below is a simplified version of its code but I tried to keep the most important parts.

```
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class SomeController
{
     private async Task<ApiOutput> RunApiForClientAsync(ApiInput input)
    {
        try
        {
            //create a httpclient with a lot of configuration
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return new ApiOutput
            {
                Data = content,
                Error = null,
                StatusCode = 200,
                Input = input,
            };
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return new ApiOutput
            {
                Data = null,
                Error = new ApiError("Error Getting the Result from the Server", ex.Message),
                StatusCode = 400,
                Input = input,
            };
        }
    }

    private async Task<List<ApiOutput>> RunApiCallsAsync(string requestId, IEnumerable<ApiInput> items)
    {
        var result = new List<ApiOutput>();
        var tasks = new List<Task<ApiOutput>>();

        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            tasks.Add(RunApiForAsync(item));
        }

        var taskResults = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        result.AddRange(taskResults);
        return result;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("rest/multiple")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostMultiple(ApiInput[] models, string? requestId)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(ApiLoggingEvents.PostMultiple, "Request received with ID {requestId}", requestId);
        var result = await RunApiCallsAsync(requestId, models);

        try
        {
            _logger.LogDebug(ApiLoggingEvents.PostMultiple, "Request ID {requestId} Generating JSONs.", requestId);
            
            var resultJson = GetJson(result);
            await SaveResultAsync(resultJson, requestId);

            _logger.LogDebug(ApiLoggingEvents.PostMultiple, "Request ID {requestId} Everything is finished. Returning....", requestId);
            return Content(resultJson, "application/json");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug(ApiLoggingEvents.PostMultiple, "Exception while returning {requestId}, message {msg}", requestId, ex.Message);
            throw new Exception("Try again");
        }
    }
}
```

Every once in a while, the caller sends the request to the API but never gets the result back. However, when I read the logs, I see the last line for the request is the line containing the text "Everything is finished. Returning" which means everything was successful. In addition, the output JSON is saved on the server's local drive (the `await SaveResultAsync(resultJson, requestId);` call is successful too).

I should mention that these types of requests are the ones that take a long while to respond. Usually around 10 minutes. Is there a setting that I need to change on the application or the IIS?

I tried to use the following but it doesn't work with the In-Process model:

```
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(o =>
{
    o.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 100;
    o.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout);
    o.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
    o.Limits.MaxResponseBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
});
```

#### Note:

The `requestId` is a unique GUID for every request to help me keep track of each request on the log file and see whether it was successful or not and if it has created the output file.

#### Update:

Upon further investigation, it seems like the requests that have a runtime more than 5 minutes are failing. Any idea what might be related to this number?

#### Update 2:

I created a very simple endpoint that waits for a specified amount of seconds, then returns back with a simple message:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("rest/testpost")]
public IActionResult TestPost(int delay)
{
    _logger.LogInformation(1, "Delay for {delay} started.", delay);
    Thread.Sleep(delay * 1000);
    _logger.LogInformation(1, "Delay for {delay} ended.", delay);
    return Ok($"Delay for {delay} worked.");
}
```

I then added the `requestTimeout="00:20:00"` to the `web.config` file, just to make sure.

Interestingly, for values such as 310 seconds, sometimes I get the result, but sometimes I don't. (Postman still hangs)

[image: Postman Hanging]

Comment: Sounds like the client making the call has stopped waiting for the response. Add your client code to your question for further assistance or investigate how your client code properly handles abandoned requests.

Comment: @GeoffreyMcGrath I tried with couple of clients but for the most cases I use Postman. As far as I know Postman doesn't stop. Also on Postman I can see the Indeterminate state progressbar indicator which means it's still waiting for the result.

Comment: Take a look at this question, especially the last answer listed, where @progsky says "adding requestTimeout to web.confg solved my timeout":
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526915/asp-net-core-2-web-api-timeout-issue

Comment: @GeoffreyMcGrath I did that. Unfortunately didn't work. Please read the update.

Comment: If it takes that long I wouldn't try to execute everything within a single api endpoint. Maybe consider using a websocket to stream responses as they arrive, perhaps via signalr for retry handling.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I agree that websockets make more sense but the API that I'm calling to get the data is taking as long as 10 minutes to return the data and that doesn't have any issues so why does this app?

Answer (score 0):

To your web.config, add the following (the value is in seconds--so this will allow runtimes up to 20 minutes):

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" />
</system.web>
```

Here is a link to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks, Geoffrey. I tried it and so far so good. I will run some tests and let you know tomorrow but hopefully, this is it.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer Geoffrey. Unfortunately, the problem is still there. We have hanging requests.