# How to increase a timeout for a specific endpoint?

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, azure-service-fabric

having difficulties finding how to increase a timeout of a particular end point in service fabric.

For example, I was able to increase the input size the end point can accept: [RequestSizeLimit(...)], is there a similar attribute to increase the timeout?

To clarify: the server side seems to not respond after fifteen minutes, so if my request takes slightly under that time, it works fine, however if the request takes over 15 minutes, the client keeps waiting, but the server does not respond.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex - What platform have you used to build your web app?

Assuming you created an ASP.NET Core MVC app, there are a couple of ways to increase the timeout. Please refer the below post.

[Timeouts with long running ASP.NET MVC Core Controller HTTPPost Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474309/timeouts-with-long-running-asp-net-mvc-core-controller-httppost-method)

Let me know if this is not you are looking for. We will be happy to help further.