# Controller timeout on dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, controller, timeout, action-filter

I have an web api on dotnet core 3.1 and I want to set different timeout specific controller action.I try to create an actionfilter something like below

```
public class TimeOutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly int _timeout;

    public TimeOutAttribute(int timeout)
    {
        _timeout = timeout;
    }

    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_timeout));
            await Task.Run(async () => await next(), cts.Token);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
            var message = $"Action exceeded the set timeout limit {_timeout} milisecond for {request.PathBase}{request.Path}";
            throw new ActionTimeOutException(message);
        }
    }
}
```

and I use it on controller method

```
[TimeOut(100)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
}
```

Although Get method takes more than 100 ms I can not get exception.Could you see any problem on code or If you have a another options for controller timeout Im ready to try it

Comment: Have u seen this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474309/timeouts-with-long-running-asp-net-mvc-core-controller-httppost-method ?

Comment: I see it but its not solution for me because it kills the connection but threads running still and I used cancellation token to exists from threads. @PerG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you see any problem on code

Yes; passing a cancellation token to `Task.Run` isn't going to work. The [token for that method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#system-threading-tasks-task-run(system-func((system-threading-tasks-task))-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) only cancels the *scheduling* of the task to the thread pool, not the delegate itself.

The only way to cancel your delegate code is to have your delegate take a `CancellationToken` and observe that (usually by passing it to other methods). I have a [blog post series](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2022/02/cancellation-1-overview.html) on the subject of cancellation.

> If you have a another options for controller timeout Im ready to try it

So, that's a harder problem.

There is built-in support for `CancellationToken` in ASP.NET Core; you can add a `CancellationToken` argument to any controller action method. However, this token doesn't have anything to do with timeouts; it cancels if the user request is aborted (e.g., the user closes their browser).

One approach is to add a `CancellationToken` parameter to your action method and have your filter modify the model binding results, replacing the provided `CancellationToken`. Something like this should work:

```
public sealed class TimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _timeout;
    public TimeoutAttribute(int timeoutMilliseconds) => _timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // Find the CancellationToken argument passed to the action
        var cancellationTokenArgument = context.ActionArguments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value is CancellationToken);
        if (cancellationTokenArgument.Key == null || cancellationTokenArgument.Value == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("TimeoutAttribute must be used on an action with a CancellationToken");

        // Create a new CancellationToken that will be cancelled if *either* the user disconnects *or* a timeout
        using var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource((CancellationToken)cancellationTokenArgument.Value);
        cts.CancelAfter(_timeout);

        // Replace the action's CancellationToken argument with our own
        context.ActionArguments[cancellationTokenArgument.Key] = cts.Token;

        await next();
    }
}
```

This will work - to an extent. Your host (i.e., IIS) likely has its own timeout, and this timeout is completely separate from that one.

Comment: Thanks much. This is what I need solution exactly