# ASP.NET Core Identity timeout in live server

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

In my local IIS, my site never times out. In my production environment, the timeout seems to be about 5 minutes and then takes me promptly to my login page.

I have tried the following to no affect:

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(o => o.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60));
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Events.OnSignedIn = c =>
    {
        c.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(5);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
builder.Services.AddSession(session =>
{
    session.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    session.IOTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    session.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
    options => { 
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60); 
    });
```

I have also created a web.config to try this

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" 
             modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="01:00:00" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```

I have even tried hardcoding the identity cookie to never timeout, only to still be logged out 5 minutes later.

I feel like I've tried everything reasonable. What should I do to have a session that is at least 60 minutes? Thank you in advance

Comment: Have u seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474309/timeouts-with-long-running-asp-net-mvc-core-controller-httppost-method ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the connection time from IIS, you can do it from the path that I have specified in the uploaded image. it's better do not change the connection time.
note: The connection time on iis is in seconds.

1. Open IIS
2. Go to "Sites" option.
3. Click on your site.
4. Click on "Advance Settings".
5. Expand "Limits", set "connection time out"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this question should just be deleted

It turned out that the Plesk server had been setting a 5 minutes timeout; and none of these IIS related settings were being honored.