# Set timeout in Action Asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How set timeout in action in asp.net core 2.0?

A request can not take more than 1 second. If it takes more than a second to return timeout.

Comment: Use a CancellationToken?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the request timeout for one controller action on IIS and IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637488/how-to-set-the-request-timeout-for-one-controller-action-on-iis-and-iis-express)

Comment: I'm using webapp on azure. No have acess to IIS direct.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it with web.config
`requestTimeout="00:20:00"`

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" requestTimeout="00:20:00" />
```